# Show that for any map $g : (Y,T) \to (Z,T'')$, $g$ is continuous iff $g \circ f \colon (X,T') \to (Z,T'')$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a set, $(X,T')$ be a topological space and $f\colon X\to Y$ be a map.

There is $T = \{\,V \subset  Y \mid f^{-1} (V) \in T'\,\}$.

I have to show that for any map $g : (Y,T) \to (Z,T'')$, $g$ is continuous iff $g \circ f \colon (X,T') \to (Z,T'')$ is continuous.

It is somewhat like associative law, but  I cannot even start the proof. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean for $g$ to be continuous? Precisely that, for every open $U \in T''$ we have $g^{-1}(U)$ open in $T$. This is equivalent to $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U))$ being open in $T'$, i.e. $g \circ f$ is continuous.

Comment: I studied that continous at x0 mean if for any neighborhood V of f(x0), there is open neighborhood u of x0 such that f(u) is a subset of V

Comment: That definition is equivalent to the one I used! If it's not obvious to you why this is the case, try changing my proof over to your definition. Pick any $x \in X$ and open neighbourhood $V$ of $g(f(x))$. Can you show that $g \circ f$ is continuous using your definition, assuming $g$ is continuous?

Comment: Can you copy that reply and paste on 'add an answer' ?? I have a difficulty in reading the words like $V$ ...

Comment: Um... No, because it's not a different answer. Do you mean you can't see the LaTeX? The comment said "Pick any x in X and open neighbourhood V of g(f(x)). Can you show that gf is continuous using your definition, assuming g is continuous?"

Comment: Now I can see the latex. Thanks to your hint I showed that assuming g is conti. , g○f is conti. But for the converse, I have a problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Pick some $y \in Y$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $g(y)$, and assume that $g \circ f$ is continuous, and try to use the same type of argument as before.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $g$ is continuous if $gf$ is.

Notation: For  any function $h$ with domain $H$ and any $S\subset H$ let $h''S=\{h(t):t\in S\}.$ (Note: $ h''S $ is read: $h$ double-prime $S$.)

(i).For $U\in T'$ we have $f^{-1}f''U=U\in T'$. So $f''U\in T$ for all $U\in T'$ by def'n of $T$.

Suppose $gf$ is continuous.

(ii).Case 1. When $f$ is a surjection: For $W\in T''$ let $U=(gf)^{-1}W.$ Then we  have $U\in T'$ by continuity of $ gf. $  So $f''U\in T$ by (i).  $$\text { We have }\quad  g^{-1}W=f''U\in T$$ because,from the def'n of  $U, $ we have $$q\in f''U\iff  \exists p\;( (gf)(p)\in W\land f(p)=q)\iff$$ $$\iff  \exists p\;(f(p)=q\land g(q)\in W)$$ but since $f$ is a surjection the last line above is equivalent to  $g(q)\in W.$

(iii). Case 2. When $f$ is not a surjection, the domain of $g$ is $f''X$ and we take the subspace topology $T^*=\{V\cap f''X: V\in T\}$ on $f''X. $ Then with $Y^*=f''X $ and the surjection  $f:X\to Y^*$ we have $T^*=\{V\subset Y^*: f^{-1}V\in T'\}. $ So Case 1 applies with $Y^*$ and $T^*$ in place of $Y$ and $T.$